# How Can I customize the Tag Color in Azure Board?

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

I want to customize the Tag Colors for my team. And I found the description in the following places in the article of learn.microsoft.com [Customize cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

But when I open my settings, I do not have a menu point called `Tag Colors`:
[image: Tag Color in the Menu Structure]

Some of the menu points are missing.

Even in the same documentation, there are two different menu structure. A little bit earlier the article shows a different menu structure, same as I have:
[image: Tag Color Not in the Menu Structure]

How can access more menu points?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second image of your post shows the task board settings. You get here by selecting **Sprints** in the menu on the left pane and then clicking *Settings* icon in the top right corner.

In order to find the tag colors option you should open the settings of the kanban board, the one containing the PBIs. If you navigate to the **Boards** in the menu of the left pane, then select the board from the dropdown and afterwards click the *Settings* icon, you'll see what you need:

[image]